# MySQL order by multiple fields

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have this table:

```
id   updateTime  writeTime 
------------------------------
1     null       2017-04-05 
2     null       2017-04-01 
3    2017-04-02  2017-04-02
4    2017-04-02  2017-03-31
```

I want this result:

```
id   updateTime  writeTime 
------------------------------
1     null       2017-04-05 
3    2017-04-02  2017-04-02
4    2017-04-02  2017-03-31
2     null       2017-04-01  `
```

But when I use `ORDER BY updateTime, writeTime DESC`, I usually get:

```
id   updateTime  writeTime 
------------------------------
3    2017-04-02  2017-04-02
4    2017-04-02  2017-03-31
1     null       2017-04-05 
2     null       2017-04-01  `
```

Comment: What is the sorting logic of the desired result?

Comment: I would copy the value of `writeTime` into `updateTime` for rows that have not been updated. This way you can order by `updateTime` using an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to sort by updateTime. If that's null, sort by Writetime. In case of equal updateTime, sort by writeTime.

You can use coalesce for this:

```
select *
from your_table
order by coalesce(updateTime, writeTime) desc, writeTime desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to order by the greatest date :

```
select 
   *
from your_table
order by coalesce(GREATEST(updateTime, writeTime),updateTime, writeTime) desc;
```